# Paraview too slow

Tags: opengl, data-visualization, paraview, visualizer

I'm trying to visualize data on Paraview but it is too slow. Running on Win10 it seems to block, running on Ubuntu (virtual on Win10), it does not block but it is too slow that it is not usable. I think there is some problem with OpenGL compatibility, but I don't know how to solve. I've looked around and I've just found not clear information. In my case, I think it's important to use Paraview directly in Win10. I have a machine with 32GB of RAM, Intel Processors 8 cores 3.65Ghz, and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti. Others can watch the same file. The complete data set is in a folder of about 4GB, I opened just the file *.case*. Can someone help me these issues in the visualization? Which other solution can I find with Paraview?

Comment: I'm ok if someone vote negatively my question because it could be very detailed on the web. But I think you should show it giving me some more examples as a solved problem. Only negative don't help!!

Comment: You have great specs, shouldn't be facing this problem. 

In Windows10, I noticed that ParaView takes more time to initialize but after that, it runs smoothly. 

I would try:
1) Others versions of ParaView
2) Different datasets(sizes and formats)

To see if the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky question to answer without additional details. Many things could be going on that could affect client-server performance. ParaView offers several parameters can be tweaked to explore potential ways to overcome the issue. I'd suggest **Chapter 15: REMOTE AND PARALLEL VISUALIZATION**, from the [ParaView Guide](http://www.paraview.org/paraview-guide/) as a starting point.

Comment: start by ensuring you have latest OpenGL drivers on Windows machine. Then make sure your drivers are indeed being use. Go to the About dialog in ParaView. what does it save for OpenGL version/drivers being used? Try using the latest version of ParaView (currently 5.3). Not sure which version are you referring to. Try to reproduce the problem with builtin sources e.g. a high resolution Sphere source.